# Understanding d3.scaleQuantile() for choropleth map

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am currently building a choropleth map in Angular 2 using the following as a guide:
http://cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/view/cp78-sack-et-al/1359

So far everything works well except the `d3.scaleQuantile().range()` function.

In d3 version 3, the above function used to be `d3.scale.quantile().range()`.

In the map tutorial above, which uses version 3, `d3.scale.quantile().range()` accepts a list of colors: `[“#D4B9DA”,“#C994C7”, “#DF65B0”, “#DD1C77”, “#980043”]`. However, this does not seem to apply to the new `d3.scaleQuantile().range()` function in version 4, when I put the same list in.

The console gives an error of `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.)` and in Webstorm, the error says `Argument types do not match parameters`

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to use the range function to set the colors, I would appreciate it. Relevant portions of the code below.

```
colorScale(csvData: any): any {

    var range = [];

    var color = d3.scaleQuantile()
        .range(range);

    var domainArray = [];

    for (var i in csvData){
        domainArray.push(Number(csvData[i]["PROP"]));
    };

    //pass array of expressed values as domain
    color.domain(domainArray);

    return color;    //return the color scale generator
}

choropleth(d: any, recolorMap: any): any{

    //get data value
    var value = d.properties["PROP"];
    //if value exists, assign it a color; otherwise assign gray
    if (value) {
        return recolorMap(value);
    } else {
        return "#ccc";
    };
};

buildMap(csvData: any){
    //code removed to keep short
   var recolorMap = this.colorScale(csvData);

   this.g = this.svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(xFeatures)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", this.geoPath)
            .style("fill", (d) => { //color enumeration units
                return this.choropleth(d, recolorMap)
            });
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `csvData`? It looks like there might be a parsing error because you're converting `csvData[i]['PROP']` to a Number.

Comment: The `csvData` variable is the csv data with the names and numbers which are applied to each state. I looked through it and did a bunch of console log statements to see what was being passed along and it checked out. It's the range function that seems to only want an array of numbers, not an array of strings.

Comment: For the code block you posted, you call `d3.scaleQuantile().range(range)`, but `range` is an empty array at that point. Is that where you're running into issues? Or is it somewhere else that you didn't post the code for?

Comment: I probably left it out by accident. I was using the list of colors from the example. After hours on this I found a solution. The typescript `typings` for d3 appears to require that whatever goes in range must be an array of numbers. So I switched `import * as d3 from "d3"` to `var d3: any = require('d3')` (which I believe just gets the regular javascript object of d3), and there was no longer a type restriction for the range() function. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

> If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to use the range
>   function to set the colors, I would appreciate it.

From the API [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#quantile-scales):

> If range is specified, sets the discrete values in the range. The
>   array must not be empty, and may contain any type of value.

So you should be able to use strings in the range array for a quantile scale in d3 v4 and if not, there is likely a different problem:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleQuantile().domain([0,99]).range(["steelblue","#aaa","lightgreen"]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',300);

var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(d3.range(100))
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr('width',18)
   .attr('height',18)
   .attr('fill', function(d,i) { return scale(i); })
   .attr('x', function(d,i) { return i%10 * 20 + 30; })
   .attr('y', function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i/10) * 20 + 30; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This should be true for other scales as well. Such as if you want to have control over the thresholds used in the choropleth by using a threshold scale:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleThreshold().domain([10,25,90]).range(["#bae4bc","#7bccc4","#2b8cbe","#0868ac"]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',300);

var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(d3.range(100))
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr('width',18)
   .attr('height',18)
   .attr('fill', function(d,i) { return scale(i); })
   .attr('x', function(d,i) { return i%10 * 20 + 30; })
   .attr('y', function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i/10) * 20 + 30; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your example gave me confidence that I wasn't crazy! lol. In the typescript version of d3 it seems to restrict the input type of range to an array of numbers. I switched `import * as d3 from "d3"` to `var d3: any = require('d3')`, which removed the type restriction and it started working perfectly.